# CSS3 : 2 buttons in new line using flex concept

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div . when I hover on it, I get 2 buttons side by side which i don't want. I have used the below code.

```css
.main_div{
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  border:thin black solid;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  
  /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-orient:horizontal;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work yet! */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}

.main_div .hover_div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  
}

.main_div .hover_div .upload_btn{
background: white;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            color: #58666e;
            margin: 8px 0;
            
}

.main_div:hover .hover_div{
 /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-orient:horizontal;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work yet! */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="hover_div">
  <div class="upload_btn cursor_pointer">
                                      <span>xyz</span>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="upload_btn">
                                      <span>abc</span>
                                    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the upload_btn to be vertically center with having gap of 10-12px;

Note : It should also work in IE10 to make the same design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.main_div{
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  border:thin black solid;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  
  /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-orient:horizontal;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work yet! */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}

.main_div .hover_div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  
}

.main_div .hover_div .upload_btn{
background: white;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            color: #58666e;
            margin: 8px 0;
            
}

.main_div:hover .hover_div{
 /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:vertical;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-orient:vertical;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work yet! */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-box-orient:vertical;

}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="hover_div">
  <div class="upload_btn cursor_pointer">
                                      <span>xyz</span>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="upload_btn">
                                      <span>abc</span>
                                    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just change `box-orient` property value from `horizontal` to `vertical`

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes. that's what I am looking for. Thank You so much. :)